# If an ESXi server is managed by a vCenter server, is there any way to get the vCenter's IP address from the ESXi server via the SDK?

Tags: vmware

Suppose you have a vCenter Server or a vCenter Server Appliance. Let's call that server "A". That vCenter server might manage several physical ESXi hosts. Let's call those hosts "B" and "C".

vCenter "A" (10.1.1.10)
-> ESXi Server "B" (10.1.1.11)
-> ESXi Server "C" (10.1.1.12)

If I use the [VMWare SDK](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/) to connect to ESXi Server "B", what API method can I call to get the vCenter IP address?

According to [this](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.wssdk.apiref.doc_50%2Fvim.AboutInfo.html), I can look at the apiType to determine what I'm talking to. How do I ask who I really need to talk to?

I'm using version 5 of the SDK if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!

It's over [here](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.wssdk.apiref.doc_50%2Fvim.host.Summary.html).

It's the "managementServerIp" property of the HostListSummary object. You can access the HostListSummary object as the "Summary" property of the HostSystem object your looking for.